# In DialogFlow CX, How to make the test case fail when there is a difference in the agent dialogue from golden to latest run?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

In DialogFlow CX, I have created a few test cases to do regression testing.

While running the test cases, When there is a difference in the agent dialogue between the golden and the latest run, a warning is displayed. But the test case is getting passed. This is the default behaviour. [Docs Link.](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/test-case#run)

**I want the test case to fail when there is a difference in the agent dialogue.
How to do this?**

Note: Agent Response Mismatch warning is displayed only when the test case run of a test case is opened.

Comment: Can you try to change in the flow like pages that are not correctly configured or intents that are directed I hope in this case the test case will fail ?

Comment: Hi Vasanthan, Can you confirm If the above comment is useful for you or not ? and you can check this [documentation](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/dialogflow-cx-retail-agent#8) also.